# What is wrong with "the result FROM" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure

In my English book, there is a sentence like this:

> "Tidal waves are the result of an abrupt shift in the underwater
>   movement"

and another sentence that is quite similar to the first one (in my opinion)

> "Tidal waves are the result from an abrupt shift in the underwater
>   movement of the earth."

My teacher said that the second sentence is wrong because of **"the result *from*"** using, but I don't find it wrong and my teacher didn't explain me much about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first sentence is correct.

> Tidal waves are the result of an abrupt shift in the underwater
>   movement

While the second sentence should be

> Tidal waves result from an abrupt shift in the underwater
>   movement of the earth.

Things either **are a result of something(s)** or do they **result from something(s)**.

Comment: Yes. Also, "the result from..." does parse, but it refers to a result in a context, not a cause ("the result from that paper X does not appear to match the result from Y").

Answer (score 1):

When used as a noun, the word *result* is followed by the preposition "of".

When it's used as a verb, it is followed either by "in" or by "from".
The choice between the two depends upon what you are focusing on —  the *reason* for or the *consequences* of something.

Examples:

Even a slight negligence may *result in* tragedy (negligence is the reason).

Nothing good will *result from* quarreling  with the boss (nothing good is the consequences).